# How to fetch and merge from URL into a project from zip file, using git?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-fetch

I downloaded a big zip file from Github, months ago. I decided to change some parts of the project. I unzipped the file contents and made a mistake and executed these lines:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -a

git fetch https://github.com/Path_To_Project
```

This last line downloaded a big amount of data, which I thought it would auto merge it with my local files.

Now, I see that my local project is not updated. Still there are a huge amount of data in `.git/objects` folder. How can I merge those data into my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This last line downloaded a big amount of data, which I thought it would auto merge it with my local files.

It would merge if you do a:

```
git pull https://github.com/Path_To_Project
```

Or, since you already fetched:

```
git merge origin/master
```

Comment: I tried `git merge origin/master`, but as I directly executed `git init` and don't have a remote set up, it says: `fatal: origin/master - not something we can merge`

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy then reverse it. Clone the repo, Create a new branch in which you copy over your modification, and merge that branch into master. The trick is to create that branch not from master, but from an older SHA1 at the time of your older zip (so from a few month ago). Creating a new branch from master and merging it would simply report all new modifications on top of master instead of merging it.

Comment: Will you please tell me how to see those "modifications" I've downloaded? I only know that somethings is in `.git/objects` folder.

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy simply clone that repo elsewhere, and you will see those modifications.

Comment: I did, but only old repo cloned. without modifications, without "objects".

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy if you are talking about the modifications you did *locally*, you didn't downloaded them.

Comment: No, modifications from Github, which I wanted to download, to update my old repo.

Comment: @MostafaShahverdy As I said, clone the repo, you will see those. Then, if you want both sets of modifications merged together, you need to merge two different repos: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1425892/6309